What was the theological pamphlet attributed to Thomas Middleton?
The Wikipedia article on Thomas Middleton contains the following claim:

Due to a theological pamphlet attributed to him, Middleton is thought by some to have been a strong believer in Calvinism.

This statement has no source. Is the title of this pamphlet known or is this attribution based on a contemporary statement that can no longer be verified? If the titles is known, has the text survived?

The Wikipedia reference is to the only theological pamphlet known to be written by Middleton: The Two Gates of Salvation. The pamphlet was published under this title in 1609. Lori Ann Ferrell's introduction to this tract in the standard Collected Works states:

Two Gates was reissued in 1620 as The Marriage of the Old and new Testament; it was reissued a second time in 1627 as God's Parliament House. Here change over time is reflected, significantly, in titles transformed to suit a volatile political climate; here, too, is a simple reason for the relative obscurity of this particular piece. If Middleton's unique exploration of the relationship between the first and second testaments has remained unprinted since the seventeenth century, it is not because of its subject, or the work's anomalous position in Middleton's œuvre, but because of the confusion caused by its various and nonattributive title-pages. It has only recently been established that the "Thomas Middleton" whose name appears in the preface to Two Gates is the poet, playwright, and chronologer of seventeenth century London.  (p. 679)

The Wisdom of Solomon Paraphrased (1597), mentioned in the other answer, is Middleton's earliest known surviving work. He would have been sixteen or seventeen when he wrote it. However, it is not a theological tract or pamphlet as those terms are typically understood: that is to say, it is not a prose work that argues for a particular understanding of God or the Bible. Rather, it is a poem that very loosely paraphrases the deuterocanonical Σοφια Σαλομωντοσ (Sofia Salomontos), usually known as the Wisdom of Solomon or the Book of Wisdom. Since Calvinists would consider this work apocryphal, Middleton's poem cannot be the "Calvinist tract" referred to in the Wikipedia article. Debora Shuger characterizes it as a "literary experiment," speculating that prudence led Middleton try out his chops on a work of dubious canonical status rather than on what Protestants would regard as the inerrant word of God (p. 1915).
Why Michelle O'Callahan refers to "tracts throughout his career," as quoted in the other answer, is not clear to me. Perhaps she is misled by the numerous titles in which Two Gates revels. She is certainly mistaken in regarding The Wisdom of Solomon Paraphrased as a theological tract; it belongs rather to the Renaissance tradition of biblical paraphrase, such as the Sidney Psalms, or Henry Lok's version of Ecclesiastes.
References

Ferrell, Lori Anne. Introduction to The Two Gates of Salvation: or, the Marriage of the Old and new Testament; or, God's Parliament House. Middleton, pp. 679–682.
Middleton, Thomas. The Collected Works. Gen. eds. Gary Taylor and John Lavagnino. Oxford: OUP, 2007.
Shuger, Debora. Introduction to The Wisdom of Solomon Paraphrased. Middleton, pp. 1915–1919.


According to Michelle O'Callahan's Thomas Middleton, Renaissance Dramatist (Edinburgh University Press, 2009, page 103), Middleton didn't write just a single theological pamphlet but several:

Middleton himself wrote Calvinist tracts throughout his career, from The Wisdom of Solomon Paraphrased (1597) to The Two Gates of Salvation (1609), reissued in 1620 as The Marriage of the Old and New Testament.

Even though the text implies that Middleton wrote more than two religious tracts (i.e. "throughout his career"), only two are mentioned.
According to G. B. Shand, only four copies of The Wisdom of Solomon Paraphrased have survived (and no two surviving copies are identical, due to press variants). It was dedicated to Robert Devereux, Earl of Essex, according to John Jowett,

As Essex had the honorific role of chief literary patron on Queen Elizabeth's behalf, dedication of a work to him was almost tantamount to offering it to the Queen herself. He was also probably regarded as the successor to Leicester as champion of the Puritan cause. In both respects the dedication accords with the poem's Calvinist-tinged Protestant Elizabethanism (...).

According to Paul Mulholland, whose article contains an image of the title page of the first edition of The Two Gates of Salvation, the full original title as The Two Gates of Salvation Set Wide Open: or, The Marriage of the Old and New Testament.
The Wisdom of Solomon Paraphrased can be found in volume VIII of A. H. Bullen's edition of The Works of Thomas Middleton, published in the 1850s.
Sources

Jowett, John: "For Many of Your Companies: Middleton's Early Readers", in Taylor and Lavagnino (2007), pages 286–327.
Mulholland, Paul: "The Two Gates of Salvation", in Taylor and Lavagnino (2007), pages 600–609.
O'Callahan, Michelle: Thomas Middleton, Renaissance Dramatist. Edinburgh University Press, 2009.
Shand, G. B.: "The Wisdom of Solomon Paraphrased", in Taylor and Lavagnino (2007), pages 461–464.
Taylor, Gary; Lavagnino, John (general editors): Thomas Middleton and Early Modern Textual Culture: A Companion to The Collected Works, edited by Gary Taylor and John Lavagnino. Oxford University Press, 2007.

